# pandas.concat produces all NaN

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to join two series with `pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)`, but the result is a dataframe filled with `NaN`s, here's what I mean:

### producing the two `Series`

```py
by_status = odr.set_index('order_status')

g = by_status.groupby(['dt', 'product_id'])
payed_orders = g.size()
payed_orders.name = 'payed_orders'
refund_g = by_status.loc[[1,2,3], :].groupby(['dt', 'product_id'])
refund_orders = refund_g.size()
refund_orders.name = 'refund_orders'
# I'm going to concat refund_orders and payed_orders
```

```py
>>>payed_orders.head()
dt          product_id
2015-01-15  10001          1
            10007          1
            10016         14
            10022          1
            10023          1
Name: payed_orders, dtype: int64

>>>refund_orders.head()
dt          product_id
2015-01-15  10007         1
            10016         4
            10030         1
2015-01-16  10007         3
            10008         1
Name: refund_orders, dtype: int64

>>>pd.concat([payed_orders.head(), refund_orders.head()], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
        payed_orders    refund_orders
dt  product_id      
2015-01-15  10001   NaN NaN
            10007   NaN NaN
            10016   NaN NaN
            10022   NaN NaN
            10023   NaN NaN
            10030   NaN NaN
2015-01-16  10007   NaN NaN
            10008   NaN NaN
```

I don't think I must've made some obvious mistakes but I really can't figure it out, please help.

P.S. the code is copied from ipython notebook, don't feel strange about the format.

### update

Tried passing `ignore_index=True`, here's what happened:

```py
>>>pd.concat([payed_orders.tail(), refund_orders.tail()], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
        0   1
dt  product_id      
2015-09-07  1000081 NaN NaN
            1000084 NaN NaN
            1000094 NaN NaN
            1000096 NaN NaN
            1000124 NaN NaN
            1000131 NaN NaN
            1000132 NaN NaN
            1000133 NaN NaN
            1000134 NaN NaN
            1000137 NaN NaN
```

### as for index formatting issue

so here's two series that won't concat well together:

```py
>>>a4.head().to_dict()
{'actual_suborders': {(datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10001): 1,
  (datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10016): 10,
  (datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10022): 1,
  (datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10023): 1,
  (datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10024): 1}}

>>>a5.head().to_dict()
{'refund_suborders': {(datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10007): 1,
  (datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10016): 4,
  (datetime.date(2015, 1, 15), 10030): 1,
  (datetime.date(2015, 1, 16), 10007): 4,
  (datetime.date(2015, 1, 16), 10008): 1}}

>>>pd.concat([a4.head(), a5.head()], axis=1)
        actual_suborders    refund_suborders
dt  product_id      
2015-01-15  10001   NaN NaN
            10007   NaN NaN
            10016   NaN NaN
            10022   NaN NaN
            10023   NaN NaN
            10024   NaN NaN
            10030   NaN NaN
2015-01-16  10007   NaN NaN
            10008   NaN NaN
```

### last resort

thanks for everyone that decide to take a look at this, great community.

I've serialized the head of above series, uploaded to evernote, contains code to load and concat them

https://www.evernote.com/l/AH4AdfgOJJROuZSfGfDR_jZvA0zEpIHgyq0

Comment: Presumably it's because your multi index has no common index values, what happens when you pass `ignore_index=True`?

Comment: where is payed_suborders refund_orders defined, they do not appear to be column headings? They don't seem to be part of either DF? So you are getting NaN since no values exist for them...

Comment: @EdChum doesn't do any good, I've updated my post to show that the index of these two series does have common index values

Comment: @dartdog they were calculated from a groupby object, grouped by `['dt', 'product_id']`, does it have anything to do with this situation?

Comment: I think that may be the issue, try assigning the result of group by to new DFs..

Comment: @dartdog I've updated my post to show exactly how I come up with these two `Series`, I'm not sure what you suggest me do, but I actually tried convert them to `DataFrame` and it did work, but I really couldn't understand why the code in my post won't work

Comment: updated as requested @Alexander, I really don't think it's the formatting issue as both series were calculated from the same dataframe (different groups though)

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work, I had to create unique values from the concatenation of the old indices on each Series.  I then passed this as a parameter to `join_axes` when concatenating:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series([1, 10, 1, 1, 1], 
               name='actual_suborders',
               index=[(dt.date(2015, 1, 15), 10001),
                      (dt.date(2015, 1, 15), 10016),
                      (dt.date(2015, 1, 15), 10022),
                      (dt.date(2015, 1, 15), 10023),
                      (dt.date(2015, 1, 15), 10024)])


s2 = pd.Series([1, 4, 1, 4, 1], 
               name='refund_suborders',
               index=[(dt.date(2015, 1, 15), 10007),
                      (dt.date(2015, 1, 15), 10016),
                      (dt.date(2015, 1, 15), 10030),
                      (dt.date(2015, 1, 16), 10007),
                      (dt.date(2015, 1, 16), 10008)])

idx = set(pd.concat([s1.reset_index()['index'], 
                     s2.reset_index()['index']], 
                    ignore_index=True))

>>> pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1, join_axes=[idx])
                     actual_suborders  refund_suborders
(2015-01-15, 10022)                 1               NaN
(2015-01-15, 10001)                 1               NaN
(2015-01-15, 10023)                 1               NaN
(2015-01-16, 10008)               NaN                 1
(2015-01-15, 10030)               NaN                 1
(2015-01-15, 10016)                10                 4
(2015-01-15, 10007)               NaN                 1
(2015-01-16, 10007)               NaN                 4
(2015-01-15, 10024)                 1               NaN
```

Also, it appears that your index has changed somewhere.  Your `by_status.groupby(['dt', 'product_id'])` operation should result in a MultiIndex, but the results of `a4.head()` and `a5.head()` pasted above indicate that it changed to tuple pairs somewhere along the line.  I suspect that this could could be the ultimate problem.

**EDIT**

I do not understand why `concat` is not working, but I managed to achieve your objective using `merge`.

First, reset your indexes.  Then merge the DataFrames on `dt` and `product_id`:

```
a4.reset_index(inplace=True)
a5.reset_index(inplace=True)
>>> a4.merge(a5, on=['dt', 'product_id'], how='outer')
           dt  product_id  actual_suborders  refund_suborders
0  2015-01-15       10001                 1               NaN
1  2015-01-15       10016                10                 4
2  2015-01-15       10022                 1               NaN
3  2015-01-15       10023                 1               NaN
4  2015-01-15       10024                 1               NaN
5  2015-01-15       10007               NaN                 1
6  2015-01-15       10030               NaN                 1
7  2015-01-16       10007               NaN                 4
8  2015-01-16       10008               NaN                 1
```

Comment: the groupby operation should and did result in a multiindex, when I convert a pandas series to dict using `Series.to_dict()`, the underlying multiindex is just converted to tuple, not that the index itself is a array of tuple, the code in my post is the exact code I used to generate these series objects, and as you can see it doesn't contain any middle steps, I'm going to post the raw serialized data

Comment: even if it's the wrongly formatted multiindex, the concat operation shouldn't result in a all-NaN frame, right? it should at least contain something, where did all the numbers go?

Comment: I noticed that `pd.merge` works too, but the thing I'm trying to do is concatenating 5 to 7 similiar pandas series, I've profiled to learn that merging two at a tine is too costly for my needs.

Comment: Why don't you open a new ticket "Possible Bug: Pandas concat with MultiIndex".  Mention the version of Pandas and Python you are using, and include the sample data.